# Error resolving gradle issue...Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am facing issue while running the app, it shows Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex error .
>   i tried all the available answer but cant find one to solve my issue, so kindly help me with it. I have tried cleaing and rebuilding project, also all libraries versions are same cant solve my issue yet. Thanks in advance.

My build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.johnpersano:supertoasts:2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.mmoamenn:ProgressImage_Android:0.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:smsverifycatcher:0.3.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'in.gauriinfotech:commons:1.0.8'
    implementation 'com.github.chenupt.android:springindicator:1.0.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

MY project.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: For test case comment `configurations ` block.

Comment: support library should be 27.1.0 https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya ok i am trying it...

Comment: @MohammadTabbara it was working fine before with 27.1.1 version too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is i reversed the play services and fire base versions to 11.8.0 and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

> Firebase Android SDKs now have independent version numbers, allowing
>   for more frequent, flexible updates.

Update all your Firebase dependencies to the latest version (as of 2 May 2018):

```
 Firebase Core          com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2
    Ads                 com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0
  Analytics             com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:15.0.2
 App Indexing           com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.0
 Authentication         com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0
Cloud Firestore         com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0
Cloud Functions         com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:15.0.0
Cloud Messaging         com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2
Cloud Storage           com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2
Crash Reporting         com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.2
Crashlytics             com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1
Invites                 com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.2
Performance Monitoring  com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:15.1.0
Realtime Database       com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0
Remote Config           com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.2
```

Release note:
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android